# Deleting a read only file using batch file or command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, delete-file

I would like to know a way of deleting a read only file using a batch file or a command.

Suppose I have a DLL file named "abc.dll", and I am trying to delete this file using the following command in a batch file:

```
del "C:\test\abcd.dll"
```

It does not allow me to do that and it throws access denied message. However if I change the read only attribute to non read only I am able to successfully delete it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Specify `/F`, it will force deletion of read-only files. Also see

```
del /?
```

However, that will not work when the file is in use.

Comment: I don't think this particular case is a "dll-in-use" one since changing the readonly (presumably with GUI) worked. +1.

Answer (score 3):

`del /f` will delete readonly files.